# EF Core 3.1 code-first with Oracle - A string is set to NVARCHAR2(2000) instead of NCLOB

Tags: oracle, entity-framework-core

I am having an application which must support both a SQL Server DB and an Oracle DB.

I have configured a basic property:

```
public string MyProperty{ get; set; }
```

When my database is generated in SQL Server, the type of the column is `nvarchar(MAX)` (great!), but in Oracle 11g it is a `NVARCHAR2(2000)` which is limiting the size of my string if stored in Oracle.

The weird thing is that this [Oracle article](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E63277_01/win.121/e63268/entityCodeFirst.htm#ODPNT8309) mentions that `NCLOB` should be the default type for strings...

Does that means that it depends of the version of Oracle used? Or the version of EF Core? Or am I missing something?

How can I achieve a full compatibility for this string between SQL Server (`nvarchar(max)`) and Oracle (`NCLOB`)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi,
I am still meeting this issue and I would be VERY interested in having an explanation to this behaviour...

Comment: I have noticed the following fact : I can see that this only applies for attributes of type string? and not string ; that is weird...

Answer (score 0):

Your link to the Oracle documentation is for ADO.NET / Entity Framework (as opposed to EF Core). This explains the difference between the behavior you expect and the behavior you observe.

You're better off referring to [this documentation for ODP.NET EF Core](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/odpnt/EFCoreDataTypeMapping.html#GUID-484E9D3A-8E42-417F-9591-F2E7305E3F6A). A little past halfway from the top of **Table 5-1** therein, you will find that string property types without any other configuration will default to `NVARCHAR2(2000)`. I strongly recommend reading past the table as well for other related details for how Oracle EF Core handles string-like columns of different types, especially this paragraph (emphasis mine):

> NCHAR and NVARCHAR2 use character length semantics. The number of characters for columns with one of these data types depend on the character set, NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET. **ODP.NET Entity Framework Core defaults to a 2-byte character set**, which allows a maximum of 2000 characters for NCHAR and NVARCHAR2 columns. **If a [Maxlength(4000)] data annotation or fluent API equivalent is used for a string entity property, ODP.NET will map the property to an NCLOB type** because the specified length is greater than 2000 characters.

If you want NCLOB, one way to achieve that is to add the following Fluent API (taken from Table 5-1):

```cs
modelBuilder.Property(x => x.MyProperty)
   .IsUnicode(true)
   .IsFixedLength(true)
   .HasMaxLength(65536); // some integer > 2000
```

[Here is another (very brief) page](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-data-access-components/19.3/odpnt/EFCoreLargeCharacter.html#GUID-AE805872-88C9-4D67-95B5-1700B5539518) in the ODP.NET EF Core docs using data annotations for a similar result.